How to fix EBADF -9 accept errors
screenshot of the error
How to fix EBADF -9 accept error?
The application running on Express.js and Node.js and Ubuntu 22.04.02 encounters an error and crashes when executing the pm2 reload command. After restarting the server and sending a request, the issue reoccurs. This issue reoccurs everytime we do the update and reload.
We tried to change the version of the node from 18.17 to 20.0 and then downgraded to 18.20 but the error is not fixed. So we are still using node -v 18.17.
